# Need to free space in /boot to update. don't see duplicate kernels... HELP!

Tags: boot, updates

Here is the ls `/boot/:`

```
@HAL-9000:~$ ls /boot/
abi-3.11.0-13-generic         initrd.img-3.8.0-33-generic
abi-3.11.0-14-generic         lost+found
abi-3.11.0-15-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.8.0-33-generic          memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-3.11.0-13-generic      System.map-3.11.0-13-generic
config-3.11.0-14-generic      System.map-3.11.0-14-generic
config-3.11.0-15-generic      System.map-3.11.0-15-generic
config-3.8.0-33-generic       System.map-3.8.0-33-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-3.11.0-13-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-13-generic  vmlinuz-3.11.0-14-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-14-generic  vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic  vmlinuz-3.8.0-33-generic
```

Is 'config-3.8.0-33-generic' my culprit? What do i do?

p.s. - I know I'm behind on updates and this is probably my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you upgrade the kernel, the older versions are kept, just in case something goes wrong with the new one, and these accumulate over time, that's why you eventually ran out of space.

You can check out which versions are installed by running: `dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii`. And then remove them using: `sudo apt-get remove --purge ...`. Just remember to exclude the latest and the currently running one in case something goes wrong (Use `uname` to find out).

You can also use `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`, it automatically figures out which packages aren't needed anymore. Just remember to check all the important features are working correctly before removing older kernels.

Comment: I don't know how to exclude the existing kernel, so I used synacptic (status>local or obsolete) and removed the old kernel through there. Updates ran fine.

Now I have to update to 14.x and am running into the same issue again 'not enough space in /boot'

Comment: If you successfully removed almost everything from /boot, perhaps that's a sign your /boot filesystem is too small.

Comment: You can probably trick the system into thinking it has enough free space by unmounting /boot, but you will need to copy the new files back to the /boot filesystem somehow.

Comment: Probably the safest way is to make two copies the contents of `/boot`, then `mount --bind` the first copy into `/boot`, that way you trick the system if it tries to remove something too. Once the upgrade is complete you can remove the cruft, clean up `/boot` and copy the important files to it. If you touch any file from grub besides the configuration, remember to re-install it.

Comment: The second copy would allow you to recover in case of a disaster by manually booting it's contents from GRUB.